# How to implement arcgis maps offline

Tags: gis, arcgis, esri, arcgis-js-api

How to implement arcgis maps offline. My client requirement is when there is no internet maps should be run offline. I have tried below example, but it's not working for me. Is there any other way to store tiles and then get these tiles in offline mode. https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/exp_webstorage.html

Answer (score 2):

I have not tried it personally, but I know that Esri's JS offiline editor says that it supports taking tiles offline:

https://github.com/Esri/offline-editor-js